# If the probability of frame being lost is $P.$ Then, calculate the mean no. of transmission for the frame to make it success$.$

Tags: probability-theory, computer-networks

Here the probability of frame being lost is $P.$ So the probability of frame reaching safely would be $(1-P).$

Now lets consider that the frame will reach safely in $k$-th transmission. That means that the frame being lost $k-1$ times and reached in $k$-th time with probability $(1-P).$ Now a frame requires $k$-transmissions exactly when the first $k-1$ attempts fail .... this happens with probability $P^{ \text{k-1} }$  and the $k$-th transmission succeeds , this happens with probability $1-P.$

For $k=1,$ the probability $= (1-P)$

For $k=2,$ the probability $= P(1-P)$

For $k=3,$ the probability $=$ $P^2$$(1-P)$
$.............. 
.............  {\infty}$

So the mean number of transmission will be $= (1-P) + P(1-P) +$ $P^2$$(1-P)$$.......... $Which gives me $1.$

But solution saying,

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kP_k$

$=$ $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k(1-P)P^{k-1}$

$=$$(1-P)$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kP^{k-1}$

$= (1-P).$$\frac1{{(1-P)}^2}$ $=$$\frac1{{(1-P)}}$

I don't understand how they multiply $P^{ \text{k-1} }$$(P-1)$ by $k.$

Comment: Possibly helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Definition

Comment: Because this is the Probability that the no of transmission times=K, so to get the expected time u multiply each time with its probability. It just slipped out of ur mind that E(X)= SUM(Xi*Prob(Xi))

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4256012/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144033/755, https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/76312/29837.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compute the "average of the number of transmissions" and not the "average of probabilities". Think of it as you are rolling a dice and a number $k$ comes with probability $P^{k-1} \cdot (1-P)$. So, the average value that you get on dice is $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k \cdot (\textrm{Probabaility of $k$}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} k \cdot P^{k-1} \cdot (1-P)$

In other words, you have to compute the expected value of "the number of transmissions". Therefore, we multiply by $k$.

Read more about geometric distribution and its expected analysis [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Moments_and_cumulants).

Comment: still not understood... Wikipedia also don't saying why multiply by k... Please elaborate little bit more..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129759/discussion-between-inuyasha-yagami-and-saslok).

Comment: @yagami please approve

Comment: @Saslok Please avoid asking specific users to help you with another question. Be patient, and wait to let others help you on their own terms. (remember, it is currently Sunday in many places in world, so not many people are available to help you)

Comment: @yagami one thing tell $k$ isn't equally likely or probability isn't equally likely?

Comment: @Yagami I seem no... You see Probability of $k$ is $1/i$ which same for each $k=1, 2,3.......$

Comment: @Yagami I don't understand this please help me...

Comment: @Saslok I have restored the previous answer. After you have understood the concept, please write a new answer. I would be interested to know a new perspective on it. :)